# error while creating a custom max function haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to create max function to compare a list of n dimensional coordinates based on the values of 1st coordinate

```
max :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
max []                               = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
max [(ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)] = (ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)
max (ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):(ar1,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1):tail
    | ar > ar1                       = max (ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):tail
    | otherwise                      = max (ar1,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1):tail
```

But I am getting error in 4th line:

```
1.hs:81:1: error: Parse error in pattern: max
    |
81 | max (ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m): 
(ar1,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1):tail    | 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things to fix it:

1. In your case for multi-item list, surround the argument with brackets i.e.

`max ((ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):ar1,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1):tail)`

2. When you make the recursive call, qualify your function name. Else, you will end up with ambiguity between `Prelude.max` and your own function. I'd recommend changing the function name as the easy solution.

Taken together, you should see something like this:

```
max2 :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
max2 []                               = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
max2 [(ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)] = (ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)
max2 ((ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):(ar1,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1):tail)
    | ar > ar1                       = max2 $ (ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):tail
    | otherwise                      = max2 $ (ar1,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1):tail
```

Comment: Also you can give `(ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)` alias like this `someIdentifier@(ar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)` and use it instead of typing all the names again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
import Data.List(maximumBy)
import Data.Ord(comparing)

max2 :: [(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
max2 [] = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
max2 x  = maximumBy cmp x   
    where 
       cmp = comparing first
       first (v,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_) = v
```

Comment: That type screams out for an alias as well :)  `type FourteenInts = (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)`.

Comment: well this is used only once and there are 12ints , 10ints, 8ints and 6ints so thought of writing it directly :P